# create tree through recursive function

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a table

`id,name,parent_id,designation` columns,

i want create tree through recursive function in php.

every `parent_id` is looking in `id` column and if user login then user can see own and all below records according `parent_id`.

like

A
|
B
|
c
|
D
|
E
|
F

if A user login then he can all(A,B,C,D,E,F) details.and if B login then see (B,c,D,E,F) and like all... if F login then he can see only own records..
Thanks for advance

Comment: Is there one to one mapping between `id` and `parent_id`, in that case, you just get a link of `ids`, it won't be a tree.

Comment: yes,my table is mapped one by one between id and parent_id

Answer (score 1):

create a function fetch_parent;

```
function fetch_parent($parent_id) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `parent_id`='. $parent_id;
    // use your own sql class/function whatever to retrieve the record and store it in variable $parent
    if($parent->parent_id !== null) { // asuming a 'root' record will have null as it's parent id
        fetch_parent($parent->parent_id); // here you go with your recursion
    }
    return;
}
```

Then just call the function with the record you want it's parents from:

```
$first_parent_id = 8;
fetch_parent($first_parent_id);
```

Notes:

- the $parent var can also be an array, depending on the mysql result set
- PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE check $parent_id in the query for mysql injection etc.